# How to remove v-tab transition slide in Vuetify?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

Is it possible to remove transition slide when click `v-tabs` ?

```
 <v-tabs v-model="tab" :transition="false" :reverse-transition="false">
        <v-tab href="#tab1" >
          tab1
        </v-tab>
        <v-tab href="#tab2">
          tab2
        </v-tab>
      </v-tabs>
```

This is not working

Answer (score 14):

Possible when you use :transition=false with v-tab-item:

```html
<v-tabs v-model="tab">
  <v-tab key="registration">Registration</v-tab>
  <v-tab key="login">Login</v-tab>
  <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
     <v-tab-item key="registration" :transition="false">
        some content
     </v-tab-item>
     <v-tab-item key="login" :transition="false">
        some content
     </v-tab-item>
  </v-tabs-items>
</v-tabs>
```

Unfortunately :transition="false" is not working on v-tabs level ("vuetify": "2.4.0")

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the validity of this regarding Vuetify 2.x but as of the current [Vuetify 3 documentation](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs/) this is the new example of how to use `v-tabs`:

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-tabs
      v-model="tab"
      background-color="primary"
    >
      <v-tab value="one">Item One</v-tab>
      <v-tab value="two">Item Two</v-tab>
      <v-tab value="three">Item Three</v-tab>
    </v-tabs>

    <v-card-text>
      <v-window v-model="tab">
        <v-window-item value="one">
          One
        </v-window-item>

        <v-window-item value="two">
          Two
        </v-window-item>

        <v-window-item value="three">
          Three
        </v-window-item>
      </v-window>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Removing the tab transition animation from the `v-window` component with `:transition="false"` works like so:

```
<VTabs v-model="tab">
     <VTab value="one">One</VTab>
     <VTab value="two">Two</VTab>
</VTabs>
<VWindow v-model="tab">
  <VWindowItem value="one" :transition="false">One</VWindowItem>
  <VWindowItem value="two" :transition="false">Two</VWindowItem>
</VWindow>
```

P.S. According to the docs page Vuetify 3 is still in Beta and may change so check there first in the future for an updated implementation

Comment: This does still work (now it's released) but you have to specify transitions for both directions e.g. `<v-window-item value="panel2" transition="false" reverse-transition="false">` or I found the fade works OK with tabs: `transition="fade-transition" reverse-transition="fade-transition"`

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your scss style tag:

```
.v-tabs {
  ::v-deep {
    .v-tabs-slider-wrapper {
      transition: none;
    }
  }
}
```